# complicated sql time calculation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables **VISIT** and **CUSTINFO**

In **VISIT**, I have following.

```
EnterTime, NextTime, CustInfono
```

In **CUSTINFO**, I have following.

```
ApptTime, CustInfono
```

And the following is my logic in simple if-else statement.

```
if(visit.custinfono==0)

{ Result=NextTime-EnterTime }

else

{

where visit.custinfono= custinfo.custinfono    

if(EnterTime>ApptTime)

{ Result=NextTime-EnterTime }

else

{ Result=NextTime-ApptTime }

if(Result<0)

{ Result= 0 }

}
```

How am i supposed to accomplish this in sql statement?

Or do I have to query all necessary fields and do the caluclation in my code?

Comment: What are you hoping as the result, seconds/minutes/days?

Comment: HH:mm:ss will be the format I want for the result.

Comment: So, given your other question about date, care to update the tags for sql-server? or is this safe for mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result in one column:

```
select
    case 
        when visit_custinfono = 0 then nexttime_minus_entertime 
        when visit_custinfono = custinfo_custinfono then
            case 
                when EnterTime > ApptTime then nexttime_minus_entertime_p 
                else nexttime_minus_appttime_p
            end
    end as result
from
(
    select
        visit_custinfono,
        custinfo_custinfono,
        EnterTime,
        ApptTime,
        NextTime - EnterTime as nexttime_minus_entertime,
        NextTime - ApptTime as nexttime_minus_appttime,
        case when nexttime_minus_entertime < 0 then 0 else nexttime_minus_entertime end as nexttime_minus_entertime_p,
        case when nexttime_minus_appttime < 0 then 0 else nexttime_minus_appttime end as nexttime_minus_appttime_p
    from
        (
            select
                visit.custinfono as visit_custinfono,
                custinfo.custinfono as custinfo_custinfono,
                NextTime,
                EnterTime,
                ApptTime,
                NextTime - EnterTime as nexttime_minus_entertime,
                NextTime - ApptTime as nexttime_minus_appttime
            from
                visit 
            left join
                custinfo
            on
                visit.custinfono = custinfo.custinfono
        ) as subquery1
) as subquery2
```

Comment: I got the following error. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Ambiguous column name 'RegDate'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Ambiguous column name 'RegDate'.
Actually RegDate is the same as ApptTime

Comment: There isn't a RegDate referenced in the query, have you added more columns to it?  An ambiguous column name error usually means you've selected columns with the same name from two or more tables, then referenced the column without qualifying which table to get it from.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     DATEDIFF(NextTime, EnterTime) as NoCustomerInfoDiffInDays,
     DATEDIFF(NextTime, EnterTime) as EnterAfterApptDiffInDays,
     DATEDIFF(NextTime, ApptTime) as EnterBeforeApptDiffInDays
FROM
     VISIT as v
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CUSTINFO as ci
ON 
     v.CustInfono = ci.CustInfono
```

In your C#, decide which of the three columns to use as your result for each of the records based on the conditions you have above.

Comment: then, I will have 3 columns. is there anyway so that I can get only one column.

Comment: easily with a stored procedure, are you aware of what they are and how to use them?

Comment: yes, i m. I will have 3 columns as the results.. and I can basically differentiate in my C# code. But I just wonder is there anyway so that I can get only one column instead of three..

Comment: As far as I can see, not in a single query, there is definitely someone out there who is more clever than me however :)

Answer (score 0):

As @MacyAbbey mentioned, you need to use more than just select logic. I haven't tested this, but *think* it will work.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE FUNCTION mydatediff(CustInfono INT, EnterTime TIMESTAMP, NextTime TIMESTAMP, ApptTime TIMESTAMP) RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 0;

    CASE Custinfono
      WHEN 0 THEN SET result = DATEDIFF(NextTime,EnterTime);
      ELSE
        BEGIN
          IF EnterTime>ApptTime THEN result = DATEDIFF(NextTime,EnterTime);
          ELSE SET result = DATEDIFF(NextTime,ApptTime);
          IF result < 0 THEN SET result = 0;
        END;
    END CASE;

    RETURN result;

  END;
  |
```

The execute with:

```
SELECT            mydatediff(VISIT.CustInfono, VISIT.EnterTime,  VISIT.NextTime, CUSTINFO.AppTime)
FROM              VISIT
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTINFO
  ON              CUSTINFO.CustInfono = VISIT.CustInfono
```

*Please excuse if my fatigue inhibits this code ;p*